# How can I inject ApplicationDbContext in another assembly?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I am trying to move some ViewComponents from the main web application to a separate class library (ASP.NET Core 1.1) which does NOT have the Entity Framework models or Identity stuff.

However, those view models depend on ApplicationDbContext to access the data (not all of what is available, just specific things). It kind of partially defeats the purpose of reusability (in other projects) if I have to leave the view component in the main web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can move ApplicationDbContext to a separate project.

[image]

Let say `ApplicationDbContext` locates in *Data* project, and `ViewComponents` locate in *Common* project.

*Web* project references both projects. *Common* project references *Data* project.